# mySQL won't start in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm having a problem with my XAMPP mySQL. I cannot start it. I had no problem starting it before, but it just stopped working today. Please help, much thanks.

Here's the XAMPP console message:

```
2:13:39 PM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
2:13:39 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
2:13:41 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
2:13:41 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
2:13:41 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
2:13:41 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
2:13:41 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
2:13:41 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
2:13:41 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
2:13:41 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

Here's MySQL logs message:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 361109; transaction id 336
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210414 14:15:15
2021-04-14 14:15:15 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: In my case this was caused by a blocked port which was used for skype

Comment: @B001ᛦ Unlikely! Skype can use 80 and 443 and therefore can block Apache, but NOT MariaDB using port 3306

Comment: Since it worked, did you install something like MySQL Workbench?

Comment: _"it just stopped working today"_ - so what did you change?